# python | move files of certain type from input/source folder to output/destination folder preserving the folder structure

Tags: python, file, directory, move

I would like to move files of a certain type within an input folder and it's subdirectories to an output folder, but preserve the folder structure from the input folder.

Alternatively spoken:
All PNG files within a folder named "input" and it's subdirectories should be moved to the folder "output" including their parent directory structure.

The structure of the input folder:

```
+ input
|   |+ input_1.png
|   |+ input_2.png
|   |+ input_3.png
|   |+ input_4.jpg
|   |+ input_5.jpg
|   |+ input_6.jpg
|   |+ subfolder_1
|         |+ 1_1.png
|         |+ 1_2.png
|         |+ 1_3.png
|         |+ 1_4.jpg
|         |+ 1_5.jpg
|         |+ 1_6.jpg
|   |+ subfolder_2
|         |+ 2_1.png
|         |+ 2_2.png
|         |+ 2_3.png
|         |+ 2_4.jpg
|         |+ 2_5.jpg
|         |+ 2_6.jpg
|         |+ subfolder_2_1
|               |+ 2_1_1.png
|               |+ 2_1_2.png
|               |+ 2_1_3.jpg
|               |+ 2_1_4.jpg
```

Goal is to get:

```
+ input
|   |+ input_4.jpg
|   |+ input_5.jpg
|   |+ input_6.jpg
|   |+ subfolder_1
|         |+ 1_4.jpg
|         |+ 1_5.jpg
|         |+ 1_6.jpg
|   |+ subfolder_2
|         |+ 2_4.jpg
|         |+ 2_5.jpg
|         |+ 2_6.jpg
|         |+ subfolder_2_1
|               |+ 2_1_3.jpg
|               |+ 2_1_4.jpg
+ output
|   |+ input_1.png
|   |+ input_2.png
|   |+ input_3.png
|   |+ subfolder_1
|         |+ 1_1.png
|         |+ 1_2.png
|         |+ 1_3.png
|   |+ subfolder_2
|         |+ 2_1.png
|         |+ 2_2.png
|         |+ 2_3.png
|         |+ subfolder_2_1
|               |+ 2_1_1.png
|               |+ 2_1_2.png
```

This is what I have so far:

```py
import os
import shutil

input_folder_name = "input"
input_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),input_folder_name)
output_folder_name = "output"
output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),output_folder_name)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".png"):
            file_source_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            file_output_path = file_source_path.replace(input_folder_name,output_folder_name)
            print("input:",file_source_path)
            print("output:",file_output_path)
            shutil.move(file_source_path,file_output_path)
```

The files directly in the "input" folder are moved, but unfortunately an error message is shown as soon as the first file of a subfolder has to be moved.
The error message says, that the destination file does not exist, which of course is true, since is should be created with shutil.move().

Does anybody have a clue why it is not working?
Every hint is appreciated.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The pathlib module has some useful tools. If you convert your folder to a pathlib.Path object, you can then use the relativeto function to get the path relative to the `input` folder. After that, just use the `join` function of the `output` path to get a new path.

```
Path('output').join(Path(file).relativeto('input'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Since I am quite new to Python, I will have a closer look on the pathlib module.

Meanwhile, I do not understand why the script above is not working.
The two print lines before the shutil.move give me the right file paths. Still it does not work.

```print("input:",file_source_path) # shows the absolute path of the file which should be moved``` 

and
 
```print("output:",file_output_path) # shows the absolute path of the new file path, which the file should have after moving``` 

Shouldn't it work then? (I know it doesn't, but I don't know why.)

Comment: Further research shows that there is a problem with the way you use shutil.move. See my other answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, you use `os.walk` to go through every file within the tree, starting with the folders and then with the files within those folders. However, the `shutil.move` function will move the folders and their contents all at once. In your current solution, by the time `os.walk` gets to the files, they are no longer there as the folders owned by them have already been moved.

A better method would be to use `os.listdir` to just get the immediate children, and move those.

```
for folder in os.listdir(input_path):
    file_source_path = os.path.join(input_path, folder)
    file_output_path = os.path.join(output_path, folder)
    print("input: %s\noutput: %s:", file_source_path, file_output_path)
    if os.path.isdir(file_source_path):
        shutil.move(file_source_path, file_output_path)
    else:
        os.rename(file_source_path, file_output_path)
```

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. I will try. Thanks for your quick help!